# Compare/Copy COORD struct; overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, coordinates

This seems trivial yet endless searching doesn't yield an answer.

I need to compare and assign.

How can I overload the COORD if I can't add a member function or friend a function?

is it just bad style to use this windows based structure?

Also, I know I can write my own class(or just do the operation once for each member), but this problem just really has me wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`COORD` only has public members, so there's no need for friend functions -- free operators should suffice:

```
bool operator <(COORD const& lhs, COORD const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.Y < rhs.Y || lhs.Y == rhs.Y && lhs.X < rhs.X;
}

bool operator ==(COORD const& lhs, COORD const& rhs)
{
    return lhs.X == rhs.X && lhs.Y == rhs.Y;
}
```

`COORD` has an implicit copy c'tor and `operator=` already, no need to define those.

Comment: nice, I'll be testing this out tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

Why not derive your on class from `public COORD` and add the required statements? `struct` in C++ is just the same as `class`, except that by default all members are `public`.

```
struct MyCoord : public COORD
{
  // I like to have a typedef at the beginning like this
  typedef COORD Inherited;
  // add ctor, if you like ...
  MyCoord(SHORT x, SHORT y)
    : Inherited::X(x)
    , Inherited::Y(y)
  { }
  // no need for copy ctor because it's actually POD (plain old data)

  // Compatibility ... ;)
  operator COORD&()
  {
      return *this; // may need cast
  }

  COORD* operator&()
  {
     return this; // may need cast
  }
  // declare friends ...
}
```

Comment: I did consider that, but then it wouldn't be a COORD anymore :) .    SO the answer is no, then?

Comment: Ehrm, why wouldn't it? Overload & and you have the illusion of a COORD. I edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: +1 for the code. But overloading the & seems like magic to me...just when I think I am comprehending most code I look at... edit: so you are saying that after that I can use `(someCOORD==otherCOORD)` instead of `(someMyCoord==otherMyCoord)`?

Comment: Nope, the comparison operators still would have to be implemented. But look at the answer from ildjarn. I like it actually. Makes it simpler. If you need no more than those things, it's true `struct` makes all members `public` so your functions don't have to be `friend` with the `class`. So unless you need more stuff member functions etc, use his solution.